# Override ToString() method

Tags: c#

I need to redefine the toString () method, to contemplate a specific situation.

When you want to connect to Oracle, you do it with the Oracle.Data.Access .dll, I am having problems with version 12 of the client, when trying to get the value of an output parameter and converting it to string you get the word "null" , on the other hand, with version 10 of the client, when doing the same, "" is obtained.

Example:

```
string  _value = "";

OracleConnection cone = new OracleConnection(this.conectionString);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("schema.PKG.sp_null_test", cone);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("po_mensaje", OracleDbType.Varchar2,300);
cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

try
{
   cone.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   _value = cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Value.ToString();
    //This returns "" if the parameter is not loaded from the database in 
    //version 10 and "null" in 12
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

I tried this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return base.Equals("null") ? "" : base.ToString();
}
```

But `ToString()` **still returns** the `"null"` word when the result of `oracleParameter.Value` is converted to `string`.

Can I make `ToString()` return `""` instead of `"null"`, when this happens?

Comment: you need to call `base.ToString()` and compare its result. `.Equals` isn't doing `ToString`.

Comment: What is `cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Value.GetType()` returning?

Comment: You'd be much better off checking for `DBNull.Value` instead of relying on any particular form of string serialization.

Comment: @mjwills: and even with that, I still maintain that explicitly checking for it is better. If only because it would be immediately clear when the other side is returning the string `"null"`. (Or, indeed, `""`.)

Comment: What Jeroen is suggesting is that you add code to check if the value is equal to `DBNull.Value` and act accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

It must be like this

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return base.Equals(DbNull.Value) ? "" : base.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In which class? this doesn't make sens at all

Comment: You can override Parameter item of Parameters class

Comment: *You can override Parameter item of Parameters class* it will obviously change the result of `parameter.Value.ToString()` **edit:** not mention that it is not possible *`public sealed class OracleParameter`*

Comment: Excuse me currently I don't have LapTop for checking it, but you can use extension method for implementation of that.

Comment: I tried this return base.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? "works" : base.ToString(); to make sure it works, but value still returns the word "null" when parameter.value is DBNull

Comment: *but you can use extension method for implementation of that.* but your answer is about overriding

Comment: Yes i can use extension methods, but i have projects with framework 2.0, and extension methods works on c# 3.0 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you are override the `ToString()` method from the `cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Value`. When looking at this code I believe you are just overriding the `ToString()` method from your **current** class.

To override such a function you need to extend the `Value`-class and override the method there. I believe this would be too much at this point.

The easier one would be to create a new method where you use the `cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Value` as a parameter.

So basically something like this:

```
public string GetValueFromParameter(var Value)
{
    if(Value == null)
        return ""; 
    else
        return Value.ToString(); 
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
try
{
   cone.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   _value = GetValueFromParameter(cmd.Parameters["po_mensaje"].Value);
    //This returns "" if the parameter is not loaded from the database in 
    //version 10 and "null" in 12
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Couldn't test the function, cause I have no running oracle server. 
But you should get the idea.

Comment: Oh missed to delete the `ToString()` at the end. Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: @ the person who downvoted - would love to hear what is wrong to my answer to improve it. Thanks!